# Automator Not Properly Filtering Files Modified Within Last 7 Days

Tags: finder, automator, filesystem, folders

I am trying to automate the process of backing up my development files weekly. I want to automatically back up the files, filter through all of the files, and delete the files that have not been modified within the last 7 days, but retain the folder structure. For example, I will have many files named index.js, so in order to know where they belong, I would like the folder structure to be maintained and the file to stay in it's proper folder if it has been modified within the last 7 days. My process so far has been to

- **Copy the whole folder containing all development files**

[image: Automator settings showing the first step I have set is to Get Specified Finder Items which is the folder I want to copy and then to Copy Finder Items to the backup folder]

This works no problem. It copies all 29K files. The next step is to get all of the content inside of the folder and filter it down.

- **Get Specified Finder Items ( The folder that was just copied )**
- **Get Folder Contents ( Repeat for each subfolder found )**

[image: 29,303 Items inside of the folder that has been copied]

[image: Right off the bat, I have an issue. When Getting Folder Contents and checking Repeat For Each Subfolder Found around 8,000 files are missing.]

**Right off the bat, I have an issue. When Getting Folder Contents and checking Repeat For Each Subfolder Found around 8,000 files are missing.
I can't seem to figure out what is causing this or how to fix this.**

If I ignore this and continue on, my next step is to filter down the items. I want to remove the items not modified within the last 7 days and since I want to retain the folder structure I want to make sure the item is not a folder

- **Filter Finder Items**
- is set to find files where the date last modified is not in the last 7 days ( this should grab all of the files that have not been modified recently )
- **Filter Finder Items**
- now I filter through those results and make sure to grab all of the same files but no folders
- **Move Finder Items To Trash**
- lastly these items that have not been modified within the last 7 days and are not folders are moved to the trash.

[image]

**So if I ignore the initial 8,000 files missing when Automator initially gets the folder's contents, and run this it does not work as intended. It does delete a lot of files, but a ton of files that have not been modified within the past 7 days are left, and I can not figure out why some files are being deleted and some are being left. I'm not sure if there is a flaw in my process or what I am missing here. Can someone point me in the correct direction for what I am trying to achieve?**

Comment: Are the ignored/undeleted files hidden files? E.g., files starting with '.'?

Comment: @zanerock no they are not, it's missing actual visible files